# F#/MonoMac project for MonoDevelop

Tags: f#, monodevelop, monomac

How can I create an F# Monomac project in MonoDevelop? I can't seem to find anything about the two together.

Comment: Did you even [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=monomac%20monodevelop)? Voting to close.

Comment: No, not just an ordinary MonoMac project; it uses C#. I want to know if there's a MonoMac addin or something for _F#_. That is, not just the code, but with all the nifty options in the project options that lets you do things like choose the app icon, what frameworks to bundle into the app, etc all from MonoDevelop

Comment: Sadly, I don't think you can create a MonoMac project in MonoDevelop using F# (yet).

Comment: Okay, looks like I'll just have to do without. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no F# project templates for MonoMac, though according to [a blog post](http://tirania.org/monomac//archive/2011/Mar.html) miguel.de.icaza did last year (under "Next Steps"), there are plans to add those templates (and templates for other languages) in the future.